# Потоки в Java. runOnUiThread. Как справиться с утечкой памяти?

Tags: java, многопоточность

При нажатии на кнопку запускается поток в котором меняются картинки в активити с определенной периодичностью, но на андройде 5.1 (API 22) появляется ошибка связанная с потоком. Как я понял для изменения UI нужно дополнительно использовать runOnUiThread, но почему на других версиях все работает ?

Ошибка *FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-299 ndroid.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.*

**Код**

```
 public void OnClickStart(View view) {

        if(!start_stop){
            start_stop = true;
            button_1.setText("Стоп");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                    while (start_stop) {
                        counter++;
                        switch (counter) {
                            case 1:
                                imageViewTraf.setImageResource(R.drawable.png1);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                imageViewTraf.setImageResource(R.drawable.png2);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                imageViewTraf.setImageResource(R.drawable.png3);
                                counter = 0;
                                break;

                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(var_int);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }}});


                    }

            }).start(); }


        else {
            button_1.setText("Старт");
            start_stop=false;

        }


    }
```

Если убрать runOnUiThread, то код работает и не вызывает ошибку на последних версиях андройда

Comment: Утечка памяти тут не причём. Вообще, обращаться ко View можно только из главного потока. Если на каких-то версиях андроида это не требуется - то это очень странно. Т.е. выход - везде и всегда runOnUiThread использовать

Answer (score 0):

Тебе надо и цикл и `Thread.sleep` вынести из UI потока в родительский, а в UI делать только  `imageViewTraf.setImageResource`.

```
public void OnClickStart(View view){
    if(!start_stop){
        start_stop=true;
        button_1.setText("Стоп");
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){

                while(start_stop){
                    counter++;
                    Resource resource;
                    switch(counter){
                        case 1:
                            resource = R.drawable.png1;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            resource = R.drawable.png2;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            resource = R.drawable.png3;
                            counter=0;
                            break;

                    }
                    if (resource) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageViewTraf.setImageResource(resource);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(var_int);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


            }

        }).start();
    } else {
        button_1.setText("Старт");
        start_stop = false;
    }
}
```